# Is cell a checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

Is there any way to determine if a cell is a checkbox?  getValues() of a checkbox is typeof boolean, true or false.  But lets say I have a cell set to TRUE but its not a checkbox. Any way to determine the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data-validation criteria type.

```
function isCheckBox(range){
   return range.getDataValidation()
               .getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX";
          //or .getCriteriaType()===SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX
}
```

### References:

- [Range#DV](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataValidation())
- [DV#GetCriteriaType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#getCriteriaType())
- [ENUM DV Criteria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-criteria)